# Sequences and sums.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i \in\mathbb{R} ^{+} $. My question is, whether or not it is satisfied that
\begin{equation} \nonumber
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=k} ^{\infty} a_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n =0,
\end{equation}
where the last equality is due to the series $\sum_i a_i$ is convergent.

Comment: That is true for any convergent series, not only for series of positive real numbers.

Comment: So far all 4 posts of you have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, the sequence equality holds for every convergent series. On the other hand, if a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $l$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-l)=0$. If you apply this to the sequence $(\sum_{k=1}^na_k)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, you get that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k=0.$$